# preferredDataLocation field in microsoft graph API not working in v1.0

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft-graph-mail

I am working on a feature where I need to find `preferredDataLocation` field for all the users but it turns out that it is currently in beta version. How can we check estimated date of this feature going into stable version? I tried to check on Microsoft 365 Roadmap but couldn't find it. I tried to use following request 
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/delta$select=id,preferredDataLocation`
but it gives the following error

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "Request_UnsupportedQuery",
    "message": "Invalid property: preferredDataLocation",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "c93a43cb-fa9d-4803-801a-5864439ad66d",
      "date": "2020-06-02T09:24:30"
    }
  }
}
```

If I use request without `delta` then it works fine. Example 
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users$select=id,preferredDataLocation`

Comment: As long as microsoft doesn't tell us, you can not estimate this date.

Comment: It is already in the V1.0 version. Please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0)

Comment: @SruthiJ-MSFTIdentity it is not working when you use delta. I have edited the question as well

Answer (score 1):

After checking in the metadata the property is not available in v1.0 for users today (only groups). Hence why it fails when requested for delta query. I created a [documentation issue](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/8581) to get the documentation fixed.

You can perform the same query using the beta endpoint today as a workaround.